# Passing functions as input to another function in another script (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

to avoid writing many times similar GUIs for my very basic python programs, I've written **a GUI generator function** in a standalone script like this:

```
def GUI_builder_function(entry_list, entry_default_list, button_list, function_list, panel_title, background_colour):
    #Entries Generation

    ....

    #Buttons Generation
    for i in range(0, N_buttons,1):
        button = tk.Button(text = button_list[i], command= (lambda i=i: eval(function_list[i].__name__ +"()")), bg = 'firebrick', fg = 'white', font = ('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
        input_data_panel.create_window(0.5*pos_width+300, 0.35*pos_height*(2*i+1) + 20, window = button)
        buttons.append(button)
...
```

It's a very simple GUIgenerator which creates some entries and buttons corresponding to the input entry list and button list, and space them in a decent way.

Now, my problem is that: **when the user clicks the generic i-th button, it must execute the function function_list[i] that the caller function has sent to the gui builder function**.

However, despite the gui builder function has received function_list[i] as an input, it cannot execute it when the button is pressed. The python engine says:

**"Name 'function name' is not defined".**

Of course it is defined in the caller function. But it will be dirty to import each caller function of each program inside the common gui builder function. **What I'm looking for is how to send to gui builder the function definition as an input to the gui builder function, which is in a standalone script as it must be utilized by different programs**.

Comment: This `eval(function_list[i].__name__ +"()")` is pretty concerning... why are you doing this? Why not use the function reference directly? There should be no issue calling this GUI generator from another script which provides a list of function references.

Comment: To clarify: suppose you have a function `my_func()` in some script, which you then attempt to pass to this separate GUI generator script... `eval(function_list[i].__name__ + "()")` will be equivalent to `eval("my_func()")`. Hopefully this makes it obvious to you why it doesn't work... if not, ask yourself, is there a function called `my_func()` in the same scope as the GUI generator?

Comment: @ddejohn Is this due to the fact that the function name actually changes when it is passed to another function as argument?

Comment: No. If `function_list == [my_func, some_other_func]`, then `function_list[i].__name__` will be `"my_func"` and `"some_other_func"` (notice the quotes). The problem is that there are no functions with those names *in the same scope as the GUI generator*. If you do instead what Bryan shows in their answer, you simply pass the *function objects* and the GUI generator doesn't need to look up their definitions in order to execute their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just reference the function directly, if I understand the problem correctly, and assuming `function_list` is actually a list of functions rather than a list of strings representing function names.

```
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    pass

function_list = [foo, bar]
...
button = tk.Button(..., command= function_list[i], ...)
```

Comment: I had already tried similarly with button = tk.Button(..., command= (lambda i=i: function_list[i])... It didn't result in errors but the function was not actually called when the button was pressed. Now I've written your code and it actually works! Thanks you. Could you explain me why lambda i = i didn't work?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo: it didn't work because you didn't call the function using `lambda`. To use `lambda` it would need to be `command=lambda i=i: function_list[I]()`. Note the trailing `()`.